# Чистый код сравнение типов, как будет правильно?

Tags: c#, cleancode

Как красиво и правильно сделать следующие условие? (Если Object равен строке)

```
if (Object.GetType() == "".GetType())
```

Comment: `if (someObject is string) {...}` ?

Comment: Работает и выглядит хорошо, спасибо=)

Comment: отправил ответом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант

```
if (someObject is string) {...}
```

Comment: Добавьте еще про `as` :)

Comment: @Aarnihauta а зачем оно тут? `as string != null` это менее оптимальное решение